# Как вывести данные?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$array = array('asd'=>"Hello",'World');
$obj = (object)$array;
```

Как мне обратиться к объекту, чтобы вывести `World`?

`$obj->1` это же неправильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Массивы преобразуются в object с именами полей, названными согласно ключам массива и соответствующими им значениям, **за исключением числовых ключей, которые не будут доступны пока не проитерировать объект**.

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)

```
<?php
$array = array('asd'=>"Hello", 'World');

$obj = (object)$array;

foreach($obj as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

[Результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac9d41106e97b823e9da3ea10610f9c5ee66783d)

```
asd => Hello
0 => World
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: Любопытно что `$arr = ["\0" => ':-)']; $obj = (object) $arr;` проитерировать уже не получится, но можно привести к массиву и проитерировать его.

Answer (score 0):

Это не объект, а массив. Обратится к нему можно вот так: $array[0]

Потому что для php ваша запись будет как:

```
array:2 [  "asd" => "Hello",  0 => "World"]
```

Comment: Я с вами не согласен, $obj - это объект.

Comment: я ведь могу обратитса так
echo $obj->asd; // Hello ;

а вот echo $obj->0; // FATAL ERROR

Comment: и я понимаю что я могу обратитса к масиву  а как мнеобратитса к скойствам сконвертированого обекта вожможно ли ето?

Comment: чтобы обращаться к объекту необходимо сначала этот объект создать. Об основах ООП в php можно почерпнуть отсюда: http://php.net/manual/ru/oop5.intro.php, в данном контексте есть массив http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php, и работать с ним советую как с массивом

Comment: @Lyrium если внимательно посмотреть то $obj і есть обект і если зделать print_r($obj) то одержим // stdClass Object ( [asd] => Hello [0] => World )